Curl and the nabla notation in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds
Book screenshot
Spivak defines for a vector field $F$, the divergence of $F$ as $\sum_{i=1}^nD_iF^i$. And introduces the notation $ \nabla = \sum_{i=1}^n D_i \cdot e_i $. And the computes $(\nabla \times F) (p) = (D_2F^3 - D_3F^2)(e_1)_p + (D_3F^1 - D_1F^3)(e_2)_p + (D_1F^2 - D_2F^1)(e_3)_p$. I have a few questions on this part.

What is $\nabla$? It looks like a function that takes a differentiable function $f$ whose domain is $R^n$ and outputs the vector whose i-th component is a function itself, namely taking the i-th partial derivative of $f$. For example, if $f: R^n \to R$, and we evaluate the output of $\nabla f$ at the point $a \in R^n$ we simply get the gradient $\nabla f(a)$. Is this right?
When taking the cross product, if $\nabla$ was a vector field, I would write $(\nabla \times F)(p) = \nabla (p) \times F(p)$ and compute. But does writing $\nabla (p)$ even make sense?
Finally, when computing the cross product I set the equation as $\langle w, z\rangle = \det \begin{pmatrix} D_1 & D_2 & D_3 \\ F^1(p) & F^2(p) & F^3(p) \\ w_1 & w_2 & w_3 \end{pmatrix}$. So I get coefficients like $D_2F^3(p) - D_3F^2(p)$ instead of $D_2F^3 - D_3F^2$. How does one end up with the latter coefficients? I guess by setting the 2nd row of the matrix as $F^1 ~ F^2 ~ F^3$ but those are functions not real numbers. Same with setting the first row as $D_1 ~ D_2 ~ D_3$. That also doesn't make sense in my mind.

I would greatly appreciate any clarification on this matter. Thank you!


$\nabla$ is no vector field.it is a stack of differental operators. That 's it. 3. You are taking the derivatives of constants. This is nonsense!


i see. so $\nabla$ is a differential operator defined on some function space. $F$ is a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\nabla \times F$ itself is a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$. and the $w$ in the inner product is also a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. (in this case n=3). thank you for your comment. please let me know if anything i wrote is wrong.

Totally right. $\phantom.$
